# How to combine two selects of one table into an internal table?

Tags: abap

I have a self-created Z-table of this structure:

```
SPWOC NUMC 6 
VKORG CHAR 4 
MATNR CHAR 18 
KUNNR CHAR 10 
OLFMNG QUAN 13 (reference VOLEH) 
WADAT DATS 8 
VOLEH UNIT 3
```

How can I create an internal table with three additional fields:

```
SPWOC2
OLFMNG2
WADAT2
```

With two different calendar weeks I want to fill this internal table to be able to compare SPWOC and SPWOC2, OLFMNG an OLFMNG2 and WADAT and WADAT2.

With

```
SELECT * FROM ZTABLE INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS of TABLE it_table where spwoc = l_kw1.
```

I get the calendar week 1 into internal table, but how can I add data of the second week into same rows?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. For example: what fields do each "calendar weeks" have in common? what needs to do if there are not exactly 2 registers for each key (i.e. less than 2 or more than 2)?

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't explain it clearly. I will try it again: I'm using the z-table to add entries every end of a week filling all the fields of the table. Now I want to be able to compare the entries of two calendar weeks. As an another example you could take a table containing the value of several currencies at a specific week. And I want to compare the value of two entered calendar weeks. If there's one entry missing for the other week, the shown values should be null or empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO Klaus. Your question is still not very clear so I suggest that you improve it further if you can. To do so simply hit the edit button to expand your original question, don't elaborate in the comments. It would be easist if you include the ABAP code that you want to run for your new internal table. We can't determine what your goal is based on the field names you use since we have no reference to what they mean or in what table(s) they are located. Since you have a number of downvoted questions consider [checking the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In Your program:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF gty_zextend,
        INCLUDE  TYPE your_ztype,
        SPWOC2   TYPE referring_type,
        OLFMNG2  TYPE referring_type,
        WADAT2   type referring_type,
      END OF gty_zextend.


DATA: lt_itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gty_zextend.
```

There You have it.

And, remember, keyword "AS" is also possible for table-fields(columns), what makes it relatively easy, to use "into corresponding fields of table" once, You specify like this , column name "another_date" as wadat2 for example. But I think, Your source for the other three field is another table, right ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have my desired structure. But If I try to select using "into corresponding fields" I get the error:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But If I get the error message "workarea doesn't contain corresponding fields". So I tried it with this:   types: begin of t_table.
        include structure ztable,
  types: spwoc2 type ztable-spwoc,
         olfmng2 type ztable-olfmng,
         wadat2 type ztable-wadat.
  types: end of t_table.
  Data: it_table type standard table of t_table.      This works now, but If I try the select into corresponding fields I get the error "the workarea it_table has more fields than selected."

Comment: The source of the other three fields are in the same table, but for another calendar week. Imagine that you want to have the price of articles at two different dates. The prices for each article and each calendar week are stored in the same table.

Comment: What a wiered thing ? Why did You even want to extenjd Your table, if those three fields are also in it ?
"and workarea has more fields then selected" is yellow and no error, but a warning.

Comment: No, the three fields are not directly in the table. But I need them because I want to compare the values of these fields. Take the example of fuel prices. I save the prices every week and now I want to compare the prices between two weeks... Or another example, the monthly  average temperature of several regions. I want to compare the temperature of two dates. Like how was the temperature off all holiday targets in January and August.

Comment: I'm currently trying with "select a.*, b.spwoc as spwoc2, b.olfmng as olfmng2,b.wadat as wadat2 from ztable as a left join ztable as b on a.matnr = b.matnr where a.spwoc = 10 and b.spwoc = 15", but I only get those entries which are existing for both weeks.

Comment: Please edit Your initial question according to so and paste Your code in it, formatted. This makes it easier to check. And as a primary hint, if results of a selection are not, what You expect them to be, Your join is bad or your where is bad.